# how does systemd replace populate-volatiles.sh?

Tags: systemd, init, sysv

In sysvinit I would have an initscript, populate-volatiles.sh, that reads a volatiles file and creates the volatiles. What performs that function in systemd? Is there a systemd unit that does this? What is it and how do I configure it?

Comment: I think this kind of question is better-suited for [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @JoachimSauer Thanks, will ask systemd related questions there first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unit I was looking for is systemd-tmpfiles. It creates volatiles/tmpfiles. Helpful docs here:
https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-systemd-tmpfiles/